# Incorporate higher order functions to calculate the average from a list of numbers using a text file

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, split, mapping, higher-order-functions

I need to write a program that computes and prints the average of numbers from a text file. I need to make use of two higher-order functions to simplify the design.

The text file (integers.txt) I will use has these numbers:

5

4

3

2

1

This is the code I currently have:

```
# I open up the file.
file = open("integers.txt", 'r')
file = file.read()

# I turn it into a list using the split method
file = file.split()

# I turn it into an integer using the map function.
file = map(int, file)

# I then use a for loop to get the total of all numbers in that list
# I then get the average
sum = 0
for numbers in file:
    sum = numbers + sum
print(sum/len(file))
```

How can I use another high order function in this program? Please help. I am still a beginner.

Comment: You need to use reduce in add of map that you are already using. They are both ho funtions.

Comment: First try to do the sum of the elements of the list. Then, to create the average of a list of numbers with reduce, think about you have to update the mean every time you get a new number.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer!

```
import functools

# open your file
file = open("integers.txt", 'r')
file = file.read()

# put numbers into a list
file = file.split()

# convert list into integers
file = list(map(int, file))

# use lambda function to get average.
print(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y / len(file), file, 0))
```

Comment: you have a syntax err